# Wifi not working after UBuntu 18.04 upgrade

Tags: 18.04, atheros, intel-wireless

As in the title description, I can't surf on the internet by wifi connection *(probably also with ethernet connection but at the moment I can't test it)* after I upgraded from Ubuntu 17.10 to Ubuntu 18.04. My device is a Dell Inspiron 15 with Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 as the wireless network adapter.

If I do ping 8.8.8.8 it seems working but if I do ping google.com or some other one It not works...

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `ls -al  /etc/resolv.conf`